# Category tree by default folded out when adding new product

Tags: magento-1.8, category, category-tree

i am using magento 1.8.1 CE.

Is it possible to have the category tree expanded while when adding new products?
Now i have to fold it out myself every time untill the right category.

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: Due to the fact, that every level is loaded, I think it is not super easy to implement, but of course you can do it by changing the block which is rendered. What have you tried? What is the problem?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I Will have a look At The block

Comment: You mean 'expanded', right?

Comment: yeah, i mean expanded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's a typo or not, but I assume you need the category tree expanded.
If this is the case, take a look at the template file that renders the categories for the product add/edit form:  `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/categories.phtml`

At the end of the `Ext.EventManager.onDocumentReady` function [there is a commented line](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.8.1.0/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/categories.phtml#L100).

```
//tree.expandAll();
```

Un-commenting this line will make the tree appear expanded. But this is not a good idea if you will have a lot of categories or a lot of levels.

Of course is not a good idea to edit a core file directly. You should copy the file in a custom admin theme and [change your admin theme](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/admin/using_custom_admin_theme_templates).